# UIAlertView includes UITextField only display on top half screen

Tags: iphone

After several hours test, in iOS 4.0 and above I found if I draw an UITextField on an UIAlertView, sdk always make the UIAlertView only display on top half screen.
This case is only available on iOS 4.0 and above.

I guess maybe Apple worry about the prompted keyboard will hide the 'Cancel' or 'Ok' button of UIAlertView if the height of UIAlertView is too high.
Is it possible to disable the above function and make the UIAlertView display at center of screen?
I hope add more controls on UIAlertView and I think I can control the keyboard return button very well.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you please brief the explanation and just say what you want a bit more directly? I think you need a textfield in the alertview right ?

Comment: Yes. UIAlertView behavior is as same as it did on ios 3.0 3.13 etc except when I put an UITextField on it, it will automatically display the UIAlertView only on the top half screen rather than at the center on the screen.

Comment: I tested and get result:

Comment: If the message string of UIAlertView composed of '\n', there can be 12 "\n", if there is UITextField, UIAlertView message string only accept maximum 5 "\n"

Comment: after 5 "\n", it will display a scrolled white view

Comment: @user262325 Yes it is the default behaviour of UIAlertView you can not have it expanded on the whole screen. After a certain height it will show the scrollable text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about iOS4 but you can move it using:

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith......];
prompt.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 50.0f);
[prompt show];
```